# Python List Separation

Tags: python, list

I am trying to separate a list that is made up of a series of two strings:

- a password hash
- a username

(e.g. `['9434e user1', '8434f user2']` and so on).

I am trying to make a list for the hash values and a list for the usernames.

I tried

```
for x in range(len(list)): 
    newList.append(list[:5])
```

in an attempt to get a list of the hash values, but I'm just getting a list made up of one item, that item being the entire original list.

What's the best way to get the two separate parts in two different lists in python?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> hsh, names = zip(*(x.split() for x in ['9434e user1', '8434f user2']))
>>> hsh
('9434e', '8434f')
>>> names
('user1', 'user2')
```

Explanation: This part just splits the items up

```
>>> [x.split() for x in ['9434e user1', '8434f user2']]
[['9434e', 'user1'], ['8434f', 'user2']]
```

Now there is a nice idiom to transpose this list of lists

```
zip(*foo) # transposes foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

```
strings = ['9434e user1', '8434f user2']
hashes = []
users = []
for string in strings:
    this_hash = string.split()[0]
    this_user = string.split()[1]
    hashes.append(this_hash)
    users.append(this_user)
```

or

```
hashes2 = [string.split()[0] for string in strings]
users2 = [string.split()[1] for string in strings]
```